# Equations in "order by" using jpql or criteria api

Tags: java, jpql, criteria-api

Let's assume mySweetTable has 2 columns X and Z.

How would I achieve this using `jpql` or criteria `API` ?

```sql
SELECT *, (3 * X + Z) AS OrderCondition
FROM mySweetTable 
WHERE U LIKE "as%" or V LIKE "as%" 
ORDER BY OrderCondition DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According JPA 2 specification result variables made from scalar expression can be used in ORDER BY:

> An orderby_item must be one of the following:
>   ...
>   A result_variable that refers to an orderable item in the SELECT clause for which the
>   same result_variable has been specified. This may be the result of an > > aggregate_expression, a scalar_expression, or a state_field_path_expression in the SELECT clause.
>   ...
>       SELECT o.quantity, o.cost*1.08 AS taxedCost, a.zipcode
>       FROM Customer c JOIN c.orders o JOIN c.address a
>       WHERE a.state = ‘CA’ AND a.county = ‘Santa Clara’
>       ORDER BY o.quantity, taxedCost, a.zipcode

Consequently following should work in given case:

```
SELECT mye, (3 * mye.x + mye.y) AS ord
FROM MyEntity mye
WHERE mye.u LIKE 'as%' or mye.v LIKE 'as%'
ORDER BY ord DESC
```

Comment: I did not think that was that simple. I will give it a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer solve your problem? Map the equation to a property on your MySweetTable entity and then order by that property.

[Mapping calculated properties with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359671/mapping-calculated-properties-with-jpa)